# Using Green's Theorem in a region with the origin

Tags: greens-theorem

I have to evaluate the line integral in the field
$$F(x,y)=(-2y+\sqrt{4-x^2},\ln(y)-x)$$
over the circle $x^2+y^2=5^2$. Since the origin is inside this circle, I can't use Green's Theorem.

I'd like to know if I'm able to create another curve (eg $x^2+y^2=1$) and then subtract it from the initial one.

Comment: There is the slight problem that the line integral is not defined anywhere $x\geq 2$ (which is a large portion of the right half of the circle) and anywhere $y\leq 0$ (which is the entire bottom half of the circle)

Comment: @NinadMunshi yes, I see it. Is there any easier way to evaluate it? Because I don't think I show do using the definition.

Comment: You can't evaluate it, it's not defined. End of story. Unless this was a typo.

Comment: To add to @Ninad Munshi's comment, the shaded region on [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fvmmhtrtlu) is the domain of the given vector field.  As such, any line integral of this vector field over a curve would require the curve to be entirely in the domain.